# Set JWT token expiration date in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jwt

I would like to set the expiration date for the JWT token to be two years from the date of issuance.

I have this code below and I placed in my function.php in Wordpress but it seems that JWT token expired quickly as it doesn't allow me to make requests due to 401 error:

```
/**
 * Change the token's expire value.
 *
 * @param int $expire The default "exp" value in timestamp.
 * @param int $issued_at The "iat" value in timestamp.
 *
 * @return int The "expire" value.
 */
add_filter(
    'jwt_auth_expire',
    function ( $expire, $issued_at ) {
        // Set $expire to 2 years.
        $expire = time() + (DAY_IN_SECONDS * (2 * 365));

        return $expire;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

Comment: You normally do not want it last that long.

Comment: can you tell us what the exp in the token is? You can inspect the token in https://jwt.io

Comment: `{
  "iss": "https://example.org",
  "iat": 1596618657,
  "nbf": 1596618657,
  "exp": 1597223457,
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "id": 3778,
      "type": "wp_user",
      "user_login": "vicentepablo4",
      "user_email": "vicentepablo4@gmail.com",
      "api_key": "3778xKgLBYRd1dqUOw83njvdw9bl"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: this is the response that I got jwt.io

Comment: Then there's somthing wrong, 1597223457 Is equivalent to: 08/12/2020 @ 9:10am (UTC) according to https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: Here's the token that I've generated now, 1599054769 is equivalent to: 09/02/2020 @ 1:52pm (UTC)

Comment: at least a time in the future, but still not 2 years. Is it valid now  (no 401 error)? What did you change in your code?

Comment: I can see that first one I posted here also lasted one week like the new one. I didn't change anything I'm using the JWT plugin auth: https://github.com/WP-API/jwt-auth

Comment: is the token still valid today? :D